# O que é uma aplicação Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

É comum ter de expor uma análise de dados em um formato mais amigável a usuários leigos. Nestes casos é também comum ouvir como sugestão que esta análise seja transformada em uma [aplicação Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/).

Mas afinal,

1. O que é um [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny)?
2. Quais são seus componentes fundamentais e como eles se relacionam?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## O que é um `shiny`?

`shiny` é um pacote do `R` que proporciona um framework web para o programador. Um framework web é um conjunto de instruções pré-estabelecidas que facilitam a criação de páginas na web. Desta forma, caso alguém deseje criar um aplicativo web para seus programas escritos em `R`, o `shiny` facilita este trabalho. Não é necessário aprender html, css, javascript ou alguma outra linguagem associada à programação web. Basta escrever o app dentro das regras que o `shiny` estabelece e o próprio pacote se responsabiliza em gerar o resultado final, como um site.

Ele inclusive vem com um servidor web que permite que os apps sejam facilmente colocados na internet para que outras pessoas acessem. Eu administro um servidor com aplicativos escritos na linguagem e posso atestar que, mesmo sem experiência alguma com administração de sistemas web, foi muito fácil instalá-lo e mantê-lo no ar.

A grande vantagem do `shiny` é gerar aplicações web dinâmicas, nas quais os usuários podem entrar com dados ou parâmetros e alterar os resultados exibidos pelo app. E o programador que vai implementar o app só precisa conhecer uma linguagem de programação para fazer isto.

## Quais são seus componentes fundamentais e como eles se relacionam?

São dois os componentes principais de toda aplicação `shiny`: `ui` (user interface) e `server` (servidor).

A `ui`, que pode estar em um objeto no environment do `R` ou salva em um arquivo no disco, é o que define o visual do app criado. Na `ui` é possível informar o número de colunas do app, se ele exibirá os resultados em uma tabela ou gráfico, como os dados serão informados ao app (se é via menus, sliders, digitando informações ou de alguma outra forma) e tudo o mais que for estético. Há pouca programação tradicional de `R` aqui, no sentido de que estas características são, em sua maioria, definidas a partir de funções implementadas no pacote `shiny`.

O `server` é onde a mágica acontece. Se meu app faz uma regressão linear, é no `server` que colocarei a função `lm`. Se meu app faz um gráfico, é no `server` que definirei que tipo de gráfico desejo fazer, os eixos a serem plotados, as cores que desejo exibir e tudo o mais.

O app é a junção da `ui` com o `server`. Ambos são necessários para que o app rode. Afinal, é preciso calcular o resultado desejado no `server` e exibi-lo de acordo com as regras da `ui`.

O código abaixo cria um app no qual o usuário entra com um valor para o amanho amostral de uma variável aleatória normal padrão. Em seguida, um histograma desta variável aleatória é gerado. Note que sempre que é alterado o tamanho amostral, o app atualiza o histograma gerado.

```
library(shiny)

# ui.R

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "num", 
              label = "Escolha um numero", 
              value = 25, min = 1, max = 100),
  plotOutput("hist")
)

# server.R

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$num))
  })
}

# app rodando

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]